# Bulk export from selenium .html to bromine .php

Tags: php, bash, file, selenium

I'm searching for a way to export all HTML test suites from one dir to Bromine. Is there any way of doing it from commandline? We already have lots of test cases in HTML format and converting it one by one from Selenium IDE feels like wasting time.

Any ideas how to do it better?

**edit**:
input - .html testcase from selenium IDE
output - .php for Bromine3

Comment: the input and expected output is not cleared, can u clarify on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Firefox add-on here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/197691/

Otherwise, try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/bin/tests-foo #Wherever these files are located...
for f in *.html
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  html -d -c "$f" | php --preset extreme - "`basename "$f" .html`.php"  
done
```